# If I'm attaching a freestanding deck to cement landing, is it ok to have it sloped and not perfectly level?

Tags: deck

When I took the original measurements of the step height, I didn't take into consideration the sloping cement landing areas off the last step. So my deck height, plus the 1" decking board is about 1/2" or so lower than the top of the step.  The attachment will butt up against the house, and extend to the right just past the pile of gravel, even with the back of the bottom step (rectangle shape).

[image]

Comment: Can you remove the step and run the deck further to replace it?